# json value is not passing using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

**JS CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('input:checkbox[name=department]').click(function(){
  var message = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
   message.push($(this).val());
   });
  var message1=JSON.stringify({"message":message});
  $.ajax({
  url:"hi.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:{'message':message1},
  dataType:"json",
 //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
   success: function( result ) {
    alert(result);
  //  $('#second').html(result);
   },
   error: function(error){
     console.log("Error:");
     console.log(error);
   }
});
})
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
   $arr_sir = json_decode($sir_json, true);  // Decode the JSON string and turnit into an Array
 // Returns the Array format, obtained from the JSON string
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($arr_sir);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
   ?>
```

where is the error?? i am not getting the output , every time it pops up NULL value. i am converting  the variable in json format then in ajax im passing it like this `data: {'message':message}` to my server.php file.

i am getting null response.

Comment: You should add var_dump($_POST) at the beginning of your .php file and see what does that output.

Also, console.log(message1) after var message1=JSON.stringify({"message":message}); should be helpful in debugging.

Comment: you dont need to json_decode `$_POST['message']`

Comment: i did the both. it is coorectly converting to json file. but in server file it is showing null. thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning any valid `JSON` from your server-side script.

Comment: can u coorect me sir, where i did wrong. my json is : {"message":["1","2"]}

Comment: That's the JSON you're passing *to* the script. Your PHP script isn't returning any JSON.